# Conversion between $\beta (e)$ and $\beta (\alpha)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Under the entry [Beta function (physics) in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)), the one-loop beta function in electrodynamics (QED) is given by 
\begin{equation}
\beta(e) = \frac{e^{3}}{12\pi^{2}}               ,\tag{1}
\end{equation}
or, equivalently,
\begin{equation}
\beta(\alpha) = \frac{2\alpha ^{2}}{3\pi}      ,\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \frac{e^2}{4\pi}                   .\tag{3}
\end{equation}

I am puzzled by the conversion between (1) and (2). I plug (3) into (2) and get
\begin{equation}
\beta (e) = \frac{e^4}{24\pi ^{3}}
\end{equation}
But this is not right. How should I make the conversion?

Comment: +1 for this question; I was always puzzled by this when I first did QFT, but brushed it aside as unimportant.

Comment: Why did you not ask your teacher who taught you QFT?

Comment: I taught myself QFT when I was around 16 from Peskin and Schroeder - I'm at university now but back then had nobody to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "argument" of $\beta$ here is actually referring to the variable which gets differentiated, i.e.
$$\begin{align}
\beta(e) &= \frac{\partial e}{\partial \ln\mu} &
\beta(\alpha) &= \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \ln\mu}
\end{align}$$
In this way, it's not a traditional function argument; it's actually an *operator* argument, and some of the usual logic about function composition doesn't apply. In more explicit notation you might want to write $\beta[e](\mu)$ and $\beta[\alpha](\mu)$.

To demonstrate the relation that the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)) shows, you can use the fact that
$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \ln\mu} = \frac{e}{2\pi} \frac{\partial e}{\partial \ln\mu}$$
which follows from the definition of $\alpha$.